# Importing the bloc package is not working

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, bloc, flutter-packages

I am trying to **import the bloc package** so that I can create a **cubit**

```
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
part 'counter_state.dart';

class CounterCubit extends Cubit<CounterState> {
 CounterCubit() : super(CounterInitial());
}
```

but it shows me an error on the bloc package, implying that the package does not exist. I have got the bloc package in my **pubspec.yaml** file

```
name: rand
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: 'none' 

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter_bloc: ^7.1.0
  bloc: ^7.1.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

I have got the latest version of the bloc but the Cubit still is not working
[image showing the bloc package error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6blXv.png)

[image showing warning once I put the cursor on the cubit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Vu5s.png)

please someone help me out, this is really giving hard time